# jQuery multiple buttons click events with the same class only working on the first button

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

I have multiple buttons having "item-submit" as class name. I wanted to dynamically append contents as shown in the code below when the button is clicked. The thing is, the click event is only being called on the first button. Clicking another button will not add any content, and worse, will reload the entire page. As you can see in the code, the variable table is being appended to order-table, which were created dynamically. This is also where the item-submit button resides where I wanted to append the contents.

```
jQuery(".item-submit").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            alert("aw");
            var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var size = jQuery("#items"+id).val();
            alert("ID: "+ id);
            var table = "<table><tbody><tr><td colspan='2'><label style='color: #800000;font-weight:bold'>Detailed Description & Price of Item<br /></label></td></tr>";
            for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
                table = table + "<tr><td><input placeholder='Enter item names...' name='items"+i+"' class='items' type='text' /></td><td><input placeholder='Enter cost of items...' name='cost"+i+"' class='cost' type='text' /></td></tr>";
            }
            table = table + "<tr><td><label style='color: #800000; font-weight: bold;'>Total Cost</label></td><td><input placeholder='Total Cost' name='totalcost' class='totalcost' type='text' /></td></tr></tbody></table>";
            jQuery("#order-table"+id).append(table);
            jQuery("#items"+id).attr("readonly","readonly");
            jQuery("#"+id).attr("disabled","disabled");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I have also tried jQuery("").click() and still nothing.

I would greatly appreciate it, if someone could help me.
And if something is not clear, please feel free to leave a comment. Thank you.

Comment: OOOOPPPPPPS! I've got it all figured out. Sorry for this. The problem is that, the buttons are created dynamically. I don't really know what happened, but I think it is because the script is not loaded for the new contents appended. What I did, I added the click functions in every content appended.. seems to work just fine.. Thanks for the inputs everyone.. :D

Comment: you are better off using jQuery's on() function for that - it can bind click dynamically for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it all figured out. The problem is that the buttons are created dynamically. I don't really know what happened, but I think it is because the script is not loaded for the new contents appended. What I did was add the click functions in every content appended. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: You can avoid having to do this by using .on and referencing a common parent element...

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(".item-submit").click(function(){
        alert("aw");
        var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        var size = jQuery("#items"+id).val();
        alert("ID: "+ id);
        var table = "<table><tbody><tr><td colspan='2'><label style='color: #800000;font-weight:bold'>Detailed Description & Price of Item<br /></label></td></tr>";
        for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
            table = table + "<tr><td><input placeholder='Enter item names...' name='items"+i+"' class='items' type='text' /></td><td><input placeholder='Enter cost of items...' name='cost"+i+"' class='cost' type='text' /></td></tr>";
        }
        table = table + "<tr><td><label style='color: #800000; font-weight: bold;'>Total Cost</label></td><td><input placeholder='Total Cost' name='totalcost' class='totalcost' type='text' /></td></tr></tbody></table>";
        jQuery("#order-table"+id).append(table);
        jQuery("#items"+id).attr("readonly","readonly");
        jQuery("#"+id).attr("disabled","disabled");
        return false;
    });
```

you don't need the each-loop in this case, just give the whole class the click-event and "this" will be the one you clicked

Comment: i have also tried that.. still the same.. dunno what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate thorough a jQuery selector, which is also what's causing the bug. Your code should probably be more like this:

```
    jQuery(".item-submit").click(function(){
        alert("aw");
        var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        var size = jQuery("#items"+id).val();
        alert("ID: "+ id);
        var table = "<table><tbody><tr><td colspan='2'><label style='color: #800000;font-weight:bold'>Detailed Description & Price of Item<br /></label></td></tr>";
        for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
            table = table + "<tr><td><input placeholder='Enter item names...' name='items"+i+"' class='items' type='text' /></td><td><input placeholder='Enter cost of items...' name='cost"+i+"' class='cost' type='text' /></td></tr>";
        }
        table = table + "<tr><td><label style='color: #800000; font-weight: bold;'>Total Cost</label></td><td><input placeholder='Total Cost' name='totalcost' class='totalcost' type='text' /></td></tr></tbody></table>";
        jQuery("#order-table"+id).append(table);
        jQuery("#items"+id).attr("readonly","readonly");
        jQuery("#"+id).attr("disabled","disabled");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: i've already tried this, as stated in my post above. :D
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".item-submit").click(function() {

});
```

is the correct syntax to use - you don't need to iterate yourself..

Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: i have already tried this.. it was supposed to work, but not this time. there are no errors in Firebug console, because the page is being reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery('.item-submit').click**...
My guess is there is an error and that's why the page reloads because all your script after the error gets ignored, including the **return false** statement, and because the page reloads you can't see the error inside Firebug (*console*).

In order to see what's happening use **preventDefault** on the first line.

```
jQuery(".item-submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // ... your code here
});
```

This way page won't reload even if there is an error in your code and you can catch it and fix it. Good luck.

Comment: i've tried using this.. but the page still reloads. Just so you know, the buttons are created dynamically by clicking another button.

Comment: i've tried using an img instead of input buttons, then i put them on a container. the page won't reload, but event is still not triggered except for the first container.

Comment: Can you post or upload example?