# jQuery click event on class only triggers the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Only the first element (the first button) will get the remove event from the class "remove-row"

### My HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="draggable-button">
    <div>Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key1]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key2]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key3]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key4]"></div>
    <div class="edit-row">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-row">X</div>
</button>
<button type="button" class="draggable-button">
    <div>Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key1]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key2]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key3]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key4]"></div>
    <div class="edit-row">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-row">X</div>
</button>
```

### My JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Remove row
    $('.remove-row').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

I hope it's not duplicated because I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369122/jquery-multiple-buttons-click-events-with-the-same-class-only-working-on-the-fir) and some other questions, but without success.

Comment: Is the second button added dynamically?

Comment: No, this is now just the raw HTML I wrote. Maybe good to notice: I dont like (in this case) to have ID's attached to the elements.

Comment: Okay create live demo

Comment: Your html is wrong. `button` is inline level element can't contain block level elements.

Comment: Both X's work: http://jsbin.com/xagimirope You'll need to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) (that's usually your best first step anyway). Also note that @Alex is correct, although the browser probably doesn't care. See [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element), [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)

Comment: I know it is wrong to have the div's inside my button, but can that be the reason why the event isn't triggering the second remove-row click event?

Comment: @JustDevelop No, your jquery code seems ok and works.[codepen](http://codepen.io/Chariz/pen/bEbWzz).

Comment: You can't write html tag in button inner html, your html is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.remove-row').each(function(index) {
      $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    });
});
```

Would do it, see this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yL6p0gRZ6niKcyVBQi4R?p=preview). Note that you have to click exactly on the (line of the) `X` to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much, great solution!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Remove row
    $('.remove-row').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  });
  
    $('.draggable-button').mousedown(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
            var button = $(this);
            var button_id = button.attr('id');
            var parent_height = button.parent().innerHeight();
            var top = parseInt(button.css('top'));
            var original_ypos = button.position().top; //original ypos
            var drag_min_ypos = 0 - original_ypos;
            var drag_max_ypos = parent_height - original_ypos - button.outerHeight();
            var drag_start_ypos = e.clientY;
            var my_ypos = original_ypos;

            //Set current order for all
            $('.draggable-button').each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr('data-order', (i + 1));
            });
            var prev_button = button.prev('.draggable-button');
            var next_button = button.next('.draggable-button');
            var prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length > 0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
            var next_button_ypos = next_button.length > 0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
            $(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {
                //Move and constrain
                button.addClass('drag');
                var direction = my_ypos > button.position().top ? 'up' : 'down';
                var new_top = top + (e.clientY - drag_start_ypos);
                my_ypos = button.position().top;
                button.css({top: new_top + 'px'});
                if (new_top < drag_min_ypos) {
                    button.css({top: drag_min_ypos + 'px'});
                }
                if (new_top > drag_max_ypos) {
                    button.css({top: drag_max_ypos + 'px'});
                }
                //Check position over others
                if (direction == 'down' && next_button_ypos != '') {
                    if (my_ypos > next_button_ypos) { //crossed next button
                        next_button.css({top: (parseInt(next_button.css('top')) - next_button.outerHeight(true)) + 'px'}); //up once
                        var tmp_order = next_button.attr('data-order');
                        next_button.attr('data-order', button.attr('data-order')); //switch order
                        button.attr('data-order', tmp_order);
                        prev_button = next_button;
                        next_button = next_button.nextAll('.draggable-button:not(.drag)').first();
                        prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length > 0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
                        next_button_ypos = next_button.length > 0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
                    }
                } else if (direction == 'up' && prev_button_ypos != '') {
                    if (my_ypos < prev_button_ypos) { //crossed prev button
                        prev_button.css({top: (parseInt(prev_button.css('top')) + prev_button.outerHeight(true)) + 'px'}); //down once
                        var tmp_order = prev_button.attr('data-order');
                        prev_button.attr('data-order', button.attr('data-order')); //switch order
                        button.attr('data-order', tmp_order);
                        next_button = prev_button;
                        prev_button = prev_button.prevAll('.draggable-button:not(.drag)').first();
                        prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length > 0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
                        next_button_ypos = next_button.length > 0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
                    }
                }
            });
            $(window).on('mouseup', function (e) {
                if (e.which === 1) {
                    $('.draggable-button').removeClass('drag');
                    $(window).off('mouseup mousemove');
                    //Reorder and reposition all
                    $('.draggable-button').each(function () {
                        var this_order = parseInt($(this).attr('data-order'));
                        var prev_order = $(this).siblings('.draggable-button[data-order="' + (this_order - 1) + '"]');
                        if (prev_order.length > 0) {
                            $(this).insertAfter(prev_order);
                        }
                    });
                    $('.draggable-button').css('top', '0');
                    $('.draggable-button').removeAttr('data-order'); //reset
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="draggable-button">
    <div>Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key1]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key2]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key3]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key4]"></div>
    <div class="edit-row">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-row">X</div>
</button>
<button type="button" class="draggable-button">
    <div>Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key1]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key2]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key3]"></div>
    <div data-value="1">Some value<input type="hidden" name="row[][key4]"></div>
    <div class="edit-row">Edit</div>
    <div class="remove-row">X</div>
</button>
```

The problem wasn't in the code I posted. I forgot to mention that I made the buttons draggable. For that, I use a plugin, which prevented the click in some way.

Now debugging and trying to fix it, thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't expect that to be the issue because the events are different, drag is basically `down, move, up`, while click is `down, up`. They shouldn't interfere. Does your original code work if you remove the _draggable_ class?

Comment: Yes I tried that, I commented the script outand the click events worked. I searched for several things in the draggable script, like activity related to the button variable, but can't find it yet.

Comment: By the way, I added a code snippet. Maybe this will give a better view to my problem.

Comment: Great. Does the _draggable_ effect itself work if you isolate it? I can't drag the buttons around on your example or a Plunk.

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Remove row
$('.remove-row').on('click', function () {
    $('.remove-row').parent().remove();
});
});
```

Comment: That seems incorrect. I want to delete the parent row of the clicked .remove-row element. I need to use $(this) to let jQuery know which .remove-row element is clicked.